# Where's yeoman's output?

Tags: yeoman

I have a coffeescript file changed. yeoman's watch task has tried to compile it and failed. Where to find the error message? Yeoman only output like following -

```
Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task
>> Unable to compile your coffee
<WARN> Task "coffee:dist" failed. Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version and it will:

```
>> Error: In app/scripts/test.coffee, Parse error on line 2: Unexpected 'INDENT'
<WARN> CoffeeScript failed to compile. Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```